# How to trigger change of option in dropdown when options can have same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

```
<option value=1 id="firstOption">First Option Text</option>
<option value=2 id="secondOption">Second Option Text</option>
<option value=2 selected id="thirdOption">Thrid Option Text</option>
```

I have two buttons, on which click change of options should be triggered, but since the options may have same value, it doesn't work properly.
Any ideas how to triger correct option, maybe by using it's id?
I can get the id of selected option, by using something like this:

```
 $('.select-change').click(function () {

            if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'First Option Text') {
            var firstId = $('select').find('option').filter(function () { 
            return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'First Option Text'; }).attr('id');
```

....
but it seems imposible to triger change by id(

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: <select id="rankchoice" class="form-control">
  <option value=1 id="firstOption">First Option Text</option>
<option value=2 id="secondOption">Second Option Text</option>
<option value=2 selected id="thirdOption">Thrid Option Text</option>   </select>

Answer (score 0):

try this here i make some changes it can triggered option if it may have same value,

```js
$('select').change(function () {
  if ($('select option:selected').text() === 'First Option Text') {
    
    console.log( $('select option:selected').attr('value'));
  }
  else if ($('select option:selected').text() === 'Second Option Text') {
    
    console.log( $('select option:selected').attr('value'));
  }
  else if ($('select option:selected').text() === 'Thrid Option Text') {
   
    console.log( $('select option:selected').attr('value'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=1 id="firstOption">First Option Text</option>
  <option value=2 id="secondOption">Second Option Text</option>
  <option value=2 selected id="thirdOption">Thrid Option Text</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From various jQuery selectors you can find option by its id or its text and select it by prop.

```js
function selectOptionById(id) {
    $('select option#' + id + '').prop('selected', true);
}
function selectOptionByText(text) {
    $('select option:contains(' + text + ')').prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=1 id="firstOption">First Option Text</option>
  <option value=2 id="secondOption">Second Option Text</option>
  <option value=2 selected id="thirdOption">Thrid Option Text</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select First Option By Text" onclick="selectOptionByText('First Option Text')">
<input type="button" value="Select Third Option By Id" onclick="selectOptionById('thirdOption')">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of properties from the [**HTMLSelectElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) interface that you can use to set/get `<option>` data.

[**.options**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml) property: accesses the [**HTMLOptionsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) of a `<select>`

[**.selectedIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property: used to set/get the index number of a selected `<option>`s

### Demo

```js
// This determines what <option> will be selected by index
var idx = 4;

function autoSelect(e) {
  this.selectedIndex = idx;
  const data = `Option ID: ${this.options[idx].id} | Value: ${this.value} | Text: ${this.options[idx].text}`;
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

/* This is a delegated click event by the .on() method chained
|| to the .trigger method set to fire a click event
|| So upon pageload, the <select> will be triggered to auto click...
|| and invoke callback autoSelect() which will set the selected...
|| index to whatever idx is...
|| It will return a string that contaians the selected...
|| <option>'s id, value, and text.
*/
$('#selA').on('click', autoSelect).trigger('click');
```

```html
<select id='selA'>
  <option id='0'></option>
  <option value='1' id="1">First</option>
  <option value='2' id="2">Second</option>
  <option value='2' id="3">Thrid</option>
  <option value='1' id="4">Fourth</option>
  <option value='2' id='5'>Fifth</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```